# permission denied error when start the elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I am working with elastic search with the postman

I download the elastic search official website

I install the elastic search in the D drive folder

I am continuously trying but the same error continuously given

```
D:\elasticsearch-8.6.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-8.6.0\bin>start elasticsearch
```

permission denied error image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccd1P.jpg

elasticsearch.yml

```
#http.port: 9200
```

when I simple hit the URL in postman then giving every time same error

GET  localhost:9200

then console error is

```
GET http://localhost:9200/
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: e185b43d-0ee1-4361-9500-62069e3346a6
Host: localhost:9200
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
```

pease help

Comment: Seemed to me to be a filesystem permission issue. Try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/-windows-file-system-access-and-privacy-a7d90b20-b252-0e7b-6a29-a3a688e5c7be#:~:text=is%20turned%20On.-,In%20Windows%2011%2C%20go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Privacy%20%26,file%20system%20is%20turned%20On.

Comment: @Fei yes you are right I give the permission of that folder but issue is not solved please help